# Why is my rebasing token balance changing over time?

Tags: tokens, balances

I bought some tokens for my wallet and noticed the quantity changes very slightly over time. I’ve seen this happen with several tokens, Im not sure why.
Is this related to the way the getbalance function works?

For example i bought some LOGE.
Balance is 2857290319.47672
A few minutes later, it is 2857334061.72867, without any new transaction.

Thanks!